# Bootstrap 3 Redirect with modal window launch

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

This topic is new and complicated for me. I have not found any information in the internet regarding this question.  
The **problem**: I have a onepage website, the general information is placed in modal windows. HTML part is made with Bootstrap 3, while other – with the help of JS.  
Each modal window has it’s own URL which looks like: *modal/category/01-name.html*   
The problem lies on search engine side: the web site’s data in indexed, the search returns links to modal windows. So, as a result, clicking those links will return only rendered blank text, cause all core files are skipped and only modal window’s code is loaded. The second problem is that the web site could be removed from the entire search, what is a critical problem.
So, how correctly this issue is treated in such situation? Could it be done in a such way: once the direct URL is clicked from the search engine or external source – the whole web site would be loaded and appropriate modal window opened?   
The **working example** with latest Bootstrap 3.x very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only could be solved by server-rending language. I've done it with `React.js` + `react-router-modal` component